# How to find matching strings upto a specific string with regex in Python

Tags: python, regex

I need to find specific strings in a file upto the line `AUTO HEADER`. I am not sure how to restrict the `regex` to find the matches only upto a specific line. Can someone help me figure that out?

This is my script:

```
import re
a = open("mod.txt", "r").read()
op = re.findall(r"type=(\w+)", a, re.MULTILINE)
print(op)
```

This is my input file mod.txt:

```
bla bla bla
header
module a
  (
 type=bye
 type=junk
 name=xyz type=getme
 type=new
  AUTO HEADER

type=dont_take_it
type=junk
type=new
```

Output:

```
['bye', 'junk', 'getme', 'new', 'dont_take_it', 'junk', 'new']
```

Expected output:

```
['bye', 'junk', 'getme', 'new']
```

In `regex`, I need to consider `AUTO HEADER` but not sure how exactly.

Comment: Side note: The use of `re.MULTILINE` has no meaning here. It only affects the use of `^` and `$` but you're not using those. Which means you can just iterate the lines and serach on each separately instead of reading the whole file

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use Positive Lookahead in regex together with re.DOTALL

```
op = re.findall(r"type=(\w+)(?=.*AUTO HEADER)", a, re.DOTALL)
print(op)

['bye', 'junk', 'getme', 'new']
```

`(?=.*AUTO HEADER)` Positive Lookahead to ensure any matching texts **must be followed by** the text `AUTO HEADER` somewhere after.  Effectively exclude those unwanted matches **after** the text `AUTO HEADER`

`re.DOTALL` to allow the regex engine to look across lines (so that `AUTO HEADER` can be looked ahead).

Comment: I don't think regex is NOT suitable in this use case. It's a very valid case to help you write succinct codes overall.   Although Regex has a rather long learning curve before you can really take full advantage of it, it is a very good weapon for us all to delegate the tasks of input parsing to Regex.  We can then concentrate our efforts on writing codes in other areas.

Comment: Thank you so much! This is exactly what I was looking for!

Answer (score 3):

You can iterate each line in the txt file and exit when you find the required key

**Ex:**

```
import re
res = []
with open(filename) as infile:
    for line in infile:
        if "AUTO HEADER" in line:
            break
        op = re.search(r"type=(\w+)", line)
        if op:
            res.append(op.group(1))
            
print(res)  # --> ['bye', 'junk', 'getme', 'new']
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't think regex is the best option here, but here's how it could be done anyhow.

You could do something like this:

`[\s\S]*(?=AUTO HEADER)`

Where `\s` will match on any whitespace character (space; tab; line break..) and `\S` - which is the opposite - will match anything that is not a whitespace character. The `*` will match all occurrences of the character set.

The `(?=AUTO HEADER)` is positive lookahead, it basically means match something after the main expression and don't include it in the result:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

This may sound stupid but have you considered not supplying the full text to your Regex match but only the text up to your keyword?
Like no reason to not just seperate it quickly before, no?

Comment: I am applying `re.findall` on whole input file, so not sure if I want to do what you suggested.

Comment: Well the easiest way would absolutely be to read the file until you get the header and then just match what you read

Comment: I cannot use `re.findall` if I do that. I feel there has to be a way to restrict the regex upto the specific string, but I just couldn't figure that out.

Comment: You can also use findall on a string instead of a file object and if your files are that small just saving everything in one string would work easily. On big files you can't do that, you would need to read line by line and do findall on those lines, then add them to your array.

Comment: I can't read the files line by line as there are tons of files and huge ones for sure.

Comment: Thats an even bigger reason to not just do ```open().read()``` into a variable but actually read line by line.

` with open(...) as file: for line in file: valInLine = re.findall("your exp", line) //do something with your stuff `